# loop addition array elements

Tags: php, arrays, loops, addition

```
 $array  = array(1,2,3);

do
{
```

> and start to add last digit to previous and put the new one as last element in array

```
    $value = $array[count($array)-1] + $array[count($array)-2];
    var_dump($value);
    array_push($array, $value);
}
while (count($array) = 10);



print_r($array);
```

I try all day to understand how to push new values until elements in array become ten

The final program should doing something like this:

1+1 =2; 1+2=3; 2+3=5; 3+5=8;....
1,1,2,3,5,8....

Comment: Standard fibonacci sequence, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: `$array = [0,1];

while (count($array) < 10) {
    array_push($array, array_sum(array_slice($array, -2))); }
var_dump($array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `while` condition is wrong: `while (count($array) = 10);` should be `while (count($array) <= 10);`